# How to implement Extend trait for generic

Tags: rust

How do I implement the Extend trait for my type?

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<types::types::NotificationEvent>: std::iter::Extend<<impl futures::TryStream as futures::TryStream>::Ok>` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:318:64
    |
318 |         let result: Result<Vec<NotificationEvent>, _> = stream.try_collect().await;
    |                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::iter::Extend<<impl futures::TryStream as futures::TryStream>::Ok>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<types::types::NotificationEvent>`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <std::vec::Vec<T> as std::iter::Extend<&'a T>>
              <std::vec::Vec<T> as std::iter::Extend<T>>
```

Isn't the Extend trait already implemented for Vec?

Comment: What's the type of `stream` in this case?

Comment: It's a std `TryStream`

Comment: It looks like something is creating an `impl TryStream`, when it should create an `impl TryStream<Ok = NotificationEvent>`.